# Best way to write a GUI (C++/Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, mfc, gtk

I'd like to know what is the best and faster way to write a GUI in C++.

In the past I've created my GUI with just Windows API. 
Now I'd like to read some suggestion about other libs like GTK , MFC , QT ecc.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Qt. It's powerful and easy to use, also, it's cross-platform. If I need a GUI for C++, I always go for Qt.

Comment: I totally agree! Qt is the way to go...

Comment: well , thanks for the info , I'll try QT ! EDIT : Can I use QT with a resource editor too ?